# applying cmds using golang doesn't take place on air screen

Tags: go

I am using golang & air to synchronize between modification and reload
I wrote the following program but it doesn't work with air :

```
func main()  {
    
    var data chan bool = make(chan bool)
    go func () {
        inFlow := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
        var cmds []string 
        inFlow.Split(bufio.ScanLines)
        
        for inFlow.Scan() {
            
            line := inFlow.Text()
            var cmd *exec.Cmd 
            cmds = strings.Split(line, " ")
            
            if len(cmds) > 1 {
                cmd = exec.Command(cmds[0],cmds[1:]...)
            } else {
                cmd = exec.Command(cmds[0])
            }
            
            cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout

            err := cmd.Run()
            common.CheckError(err , "CMD EXECUTION FAILED -")
        }
        data <- true
    }()
    
    <-data
    
}
```

when I start the prog without `air`, it works fine
how to make air apply these commands ???

Comment: what do you mean, "doesn't work with air"? air will only rebuild and restart your server after changes

Comment: the output of the cmd doesn't appear in my terminal, as you can see I've associated the cmd output with the standard output but it doesn't work